# Is fb://authorize a valid URL Scheme for facebook?

Tags: facebook

I am trying to use native facebook app's authentication credentials in browser. Planning to use `fb://authorize` URL scheme, it seems it is not working.

Is there any way I can use native facebook application user credentials instead of asking the user to login again within the browser?

Comment: So you want to log users in using Facebook's iOS or Android SDK, but without actually using the SDK? I don't think you're going to have much success here - you should use the supported [Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/) methods for mobile web in your mobile web apps, and the SDKs for native apps

Comment: @lgy i want to use already existing user credentials (in the native app) in my web application. I don't want to ask the user to enter credentials again if he/she has already authenticated in the native app.

Comment: No, that's not possible, the SDK doesn't support it

Comment: @Amareswar have you find a url schema to authorize user with mobile app?

Comment: @LuigiSaggese I did not find url schema. It seems it is not supported.

Comment: That seems very strange. If you read FB SSO so many time talk about of app authentication... More on iOS where authentication it's embedded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only do this with a native application on the device whose identity (bundle id on iOS, keyhash on Android) has been registered with Facebook.  In all cases the identity of the native application is verified, the user must approve the permissions requested by the application, and the user has the ability to revoke these permissions in privacy settings.

It would violate users' privacy if it were possible for a web site to find out the identity of a user just because they had the Facebook app on the same device they were using to browse the internet.